# How to create a KDE Plasma color scheme for titlebar colors only?

Tags: kde, theme, plasma5, color-management

I wish to use KDE Plasma's ability to set titlebar colors using window-specific rules. I know how to accomplish that in general. However, since I am setting only titlebar color options, I would like to have some color schemes that contain only titlebar-related color settings and leave alone whatever other (custom) colors a user may be using. What's the right way to accomplish this?

Is it enough to have a .colors file with only these values (General and WM)?

```
[General]
Name=My_ColorScheme_Name
[WM]
activeBackground=
activeBlend=
activeForeground=
inactiveBackground=
inactiveBlend=
inactiveForeground=
```

Or do I need to include all color sections including these which are unrelated to the titlebar color?

```
[ColorEffects:Disabled]
[ColorEffects:Inactive]
[Colors:Button]
[Colors:Selection]
[Colors:Tooltip]
[Colors:View]
[Colors:Window]
```

I'm trying to keep things simple and to avoid specifying color values which are not used and which may conflict with values a user has set. My goal is to only change the titlebar colors using KDE's window-specific rules. Those rules have an option for changing titlebar colors, and I find it does work well when set up via the System Settings GUI. My goal is to find a simple way to set it up by editing text files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sufficient to list the minimal colors to specify the active titlebar. Create a text file in the following location:

```
~/.local/share/color-schemes/
```

The file should end with the `.colors` extension. It's minimal contents can include as little as the following, where `Name=` is any name you choose.

```
[General]
Name=YourName_TitlebarColors

[WM]
activeBackground=255,0,0
activeForeground=0,0,0
```

This example will make the titlebar red with black text for the active window. This becomes very interesting and useful when you combine it with window specific rules, such as matching on WM_CLASS do that different applications have different active titlebar colors (similar to Android).